Amazon QuickSight - Input Manifest does not contain any valid URIs
I am creating a new data source from an S3 bucket for a QuickSight analysis, which is in another account. When I upload a manifest.json that contains URIPrefixes, I get the following error:

We can’t connect to this S3 bucket. Make sure any S3 buckets you specify are associated with the AWS account used to create this QuickSight account.
sourceErrorCode MANIFEST_NO_FILES_FOUND
sourceErrorMessage: Input Manifest test does not contain any valid URIs

This is my manifest.json:
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIPrefixes": [
                "s3://my-costanalysis-bucket/data/"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "containsHeader": true
    }
}

The strange part is that when I try it with a single URI, it works like it should. For example if my manifest.json would be:
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "s3://my-costanalysis-bucket/data/MyCostAnalysis-00001.csv.gz"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "containsHeader": true
    }
}

Then it works. So by my logic, the permissions etc. should be configured correctly.
I created the S3 bucket that contains data for one month, then I created a manifest.json in the same bucket by this AWS guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html. I configured the permissions to allow the QuickSight's account to access this bucket.
After that, I went to QuickSight's management panel and granted permissions for the S3 bucket.
Then I went to QuickSight's Datasets to create a new dataset from an S3 data source, entered the source name and tried uploading and using the URL to my manifest.json file.
Tried it with the different URI prefix formats and with different folders such as just s3://my-costanalysis-bucket/ or https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-costanalysis-bucket/, but it all gives the same error. I even tried to specify the region, but the bucket is in the same region as the QuickSight account, so it shouldn't matter.
Am I missing something?
